# what happen b=a[:] in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
    >>>a=[999999,2,3]
    >>>b=[999999,2,3]
    >>>print(a[0] is b[0])
    False#because it works for numbers -5 through 256
    >>>a=[1,2,3]
    >>>b=a[:]
    >>>print(a[0] is b[0])
    True#because it works for numbers -5 through 256
    >>>a=[999999,2,3]
    >>>b=a[:]
    >>>print(a[0] is b[0])
    True#why not False ???
```

what happen b=a[:] (why not works for numbers -5 through 256 )?

Comment: I think you're confusing two strange things: 1) `b=a[:]` copies the references to all the integers, so `b[0]` points to the same int as `a[0]` and `a[0] is b[0]` returns `True`. 2) refs to the numbers -5 through 256 are kept at all times.

Answer (score 12):

The -5 to 256 range has to do with the [following](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an `int` in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

To demonstrate this, notice how `id(123)` keeps returning the same value, whereas `id(9999)` can return different values:

```
In [18]: id(123)
Out[18]: 9421736

In [19]: id(123)
Out[19]: 9421736

In [20]: id(9999)
Out[20]: 9708228

In [21]: id(9999)
Out[21]: 10706060
```

This is of course an artefact of the current implementation. A different Python implementation might not do that, or might use a different range.

As to your last example:

```
In [14]: a=[999999, 2, 3]

In [15]: b=a[:]

In [16]: map(id, a)
Out[16]: [10908252, 9421180, 9421168]

In [17]: map(id, b)
Out[17]: [10908252, 9421180, 9421168]
```

As you can see, `[:]` simply copies the references. This explains why `a[i] is b[i]` evaluates to `True` for all `i`.

Comment: And the reason this is possible is that integers are immutable.

Comment: For your `id(9999)` example, it gets even more confusing:  try that in a regular Python 2.x prompt instead of IPython, and you'll see the same value coming back each time (because the same integer slot is being reused each time;  the existence of the history in IPython makes this impossible, of course).

Answer (score 6):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
```

Here, `b=a` makes b an alias of a. That means, all changes to b will be seen in a.

`b=a[:]` means to make a copy of a and assign it to b.

Answer (score 3):

```
 >>>b=a[:]
```

Makes a shallow copy of the items in list a and names that copy b. All the items contained in the new list will have have the same object ids (think pointers) as the items in the original list . This is expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [@NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13539266/915501), here's a nice illustration:

```
a = range(-7, 259)
b = range(-7, 259)
for x, y in zip(a,b): 
    print x, x is y
```

prints:

```
-7 False
-6 False
-5 True
-4 True
...
255 True
256 True
257 False
258 False
```